# What do I do if I intentionally break my fast?

Tags: fiqh, ramadan, tawba, sawm

During the month of Ramadan, I intentionally broke my fast. What should I do to make up for the broken fast?

Comment: Did you mean unintentionally?

Comment: @Yousf No, I didn't.

Answer (score 5):

#### Breaking Fast is a Sin

First of all, fasting in Ramadan is fard (i.e. the order of Allah). One must have fast in Ramadan if [the general conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawm#General_conditions) are met.

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُواْ كُتِبَ عَلَيْكُمُ الصِّيَامُ كَمَا كُتِبَ عَلَى الَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِكُمْ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَتَّقُونَ
>   "O ye who believe! Fasting is prescribed to you as it was prescribed to those before you, that ye may (learn) self-restraint."
>
> أَيَّامًا مَّعْدُودَاتٍ فَمَن كَانَ مِنكُم مَّرِيضًا أَوْ عَلَى سَفَرٍ فَعِدَّةٌ مِّنْ أَيَّامٍ أُخَرَ وَعَلَى الَّذِينَ يُطِيقُونَهُ فِدْيَةٌ طَعَامُ مِسْكِينٍ فَمَن تَطَوَّعَ خَيْرًا فَهُوَ خَيْرٌ لَّهُ وَأَن تَصُومُواْ خَيْرٌ لَّكُمْ إِن كُنتُمْ تَعْلَمُونَ
>   "(Fast) a certain number of days; and (for) him who is sick among you, or on a journey, (the same) number of other days; and for those who can afford it there is a ransom: the feeding of a man in need - but whoso doeth good of his own accord, it is better for him: and that ye fast is better for you if ye did but know."
>
> شَهْرُ رَمَضَانَ الَّذِيَ أُنزِلَ فِيهِ الْقُرْآنُ هُدًى لِّلنَّاسِ وَبَيِّنَاتٍ مِّنَ الْهُدَى وَالْفُرْقَانِ فَمَن شَهِدَ مِنكُمُ الشَّهْرَ فَلْيَصُمْهُ وَمَن كَانَ مَرِيضًا أَوْ عَلَى سَفَرٍ فَعِدَّةٌ مِّنْ أَيَّامٍ أُخَرَ يُرِيدُ اللّهُ بِكُمُ الْيُسْرَ وَلاَ يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ الْعُسْرَ وَلِتُكْمِلُواْ الْعِدَّةَ وَلِتُكَبِّرُواْ اللّهَ عَلَى مَا هَدَاكُمْ وَلَعَلَّكُمْ تَشْكُرُونَ
>   "The month of Ramadan in which was revealed the Qur'an, a guidance for mankind, and clear proofs of the guidance, and the Criterion (of right and wrong). And whosoever of you is present, let him fast the month, and whosoever of you is sick or on a journey, (let him fast the same) number of other days. Allah desireth for you ease; He desireth not hardship for you; and (He desireth) that ye should complete the period, and that ye should magnify Allah for having guided you, and that peradventure ye may be thankful."
>
> وَإِذَا سَأَلَكَ عِبَادِي عَنِّي فَإِنِّي قَرِيبٌ أُجِيبُ دَعْوَةَ الدَّاعِ إِذَا دَعَانِ فَلْيَسْتَجِيبُواْ لِي وَلْيُؤْمِنُواْ بِي لَعَلَّهُمْ يَرْشُدُونَ
>   And when My servants ask you, [O Muhammad], concerning Me - indeed I am near. I respond to the invocation of the supplicant when he calls upon Me. So let them respond to Me [by obedience] and believe in Me that they may be [rightly] guided.
>
> أُحِلَّ لَكُمْ لَيْلَةَ الصِّيَامِ الرَّفَثُ إِلَى نِسَآئِكُمْ هُنَّ لِبَاسٌ لَّكُمْ وَأَنتُمْ لِبَاسٌ لَّهُنَّ عَلِمَ اللّهُ أَنَّكُمْ كُنتُمْ تَخْتانُونَ أَنفُسَكُمْ فَتَابَ عَلَيْكُمْ وَعَفَا عَنكُمْ فَالآنَ بَاشِرُوهُنَّ وَابْتَغُواْ مَا كَتَبَ اللّهُ لَكُمْ وَكُلُواْ وَاشْرَبُواْ حَتَّى يَتَبَيَّنَ لَكُمُ الْخَيْطُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الْخَيْطِ الأَسْوَدِ مِنَ الْفَجْرِ ثُمَّ أَتِمُّواْ الصِّيَامَ إِلَى الَّليْلِ وَلاَ تُبَاشِرُوهُنَّ وَأَنتُمْ عَاكِفُونَ فِي الْمَسَاجِدِ تِلْكَ حُدُودُ اللّهِ فَلاَ تَقْرَبُوهَا كَذَلِكَ يُبَيِّنُ اللّهُ آيَاتِهِ لِلنَّاسِ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَتَّقُونَ
>   "It is made lawful for you to go unto your wives on the night of the fast. They are raiment for you and ye are raiment for them. Allah is Aware that ye were deceiving yourselves in this respect and He hath turned in mercy toward you and relieved you. So hold intercourse with them and seek that which Allah hath ordained for you, and eat and drink until the white thread becometh distinct to you from the black thread of the dawn. Then strictly observe the fast till nightfall and touch them not, but be at your devotions in the mosques. These are the limits imposed by Allah, so approach them not. Thus Allah expoundeth His revelation to mankind that they may ward off (evil)."
>   [Bakara 183-187 (2 / 183-187)](http://quran.com/2/160)

A muslim must seek for forgiveness (tawba) when he/she commits a sin. In general (not only for breaking a fast), making tawba after a sin is fard.

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا تُوبُوا إِلَى اللَّهِ تَوْبَةً نَّصُوحًا عَسَى رَبُّكُمْ أَن يُكَفِّرَ عَنكُمْ سَيِّئَاتِكُمْ وَيُدْخِلَكُمْ جَنَّاتٍ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا الْأَنْهَارُ يَوْمَ لَا يُخْزِي اللَّهُ النَّبِيَّ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا مَعَهُ نُورُهُمْ يَسْعَى بَيْنَ أَيْدِيهِمْ وَبِأَيْمَانِهِمْ يَقُولُونَ رَبَّنَا أَتْمِمْ لَنَا نُورَنَا وَاغْفِرْ لَنَا إِنَّكَ عَلَى كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ
>   O you who have believed, repent to Allah with sincere repentance. Perhaps your Lord will remove from you your misdeeds and admit you into gardens beneath which rivers flow [on] the Day when Allah will not disgrace the Prophet and those who believed with him. Their light will proceed before them and on their right; they will say, "Our Lord, perfect for us our light and forgive us. Indeed, You are over all things competent."
>   [Tahrim 8 (66/8)](http://quran.com/66/8)

and,

> إِلاَّ الَّذِينَ تَابُواْ وَأَصْلَحُواْ وَبَيَّنُواْ فَأُوْلَئِكَ أَتُوبُ عَلَيْهِمْ وَأَنَا التَّوَّابُ الرَّحِيمُ
>   Except for those who repent and correct themselves and make evident [what they concealed]. Those - I will accept their repentance, and I am the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful.
>   [Bakara 160 (2/160)](http://quran.com/66/8)

Therefore, one must never break his/her fast unless there are situations that exempt the faster from his/her fast, like becoming diseased or going on a travel. If one happens to bread his/her fast, he/she must ask Allah for forgiveness, and repent from his/her this sin.

#### Is There Any Practice Other Than Tawba?

There is no ayah or direct order from the prophet about further practices, but there is a hadith about it:

> A man came to the nabi Muhammad (pbuh) and said "I am ruined!". Nabi Muhammad asked him "What is the thing that ruins you?". The man replied "I had intercourse with my wife in Ramadan.". Then Rasulullah said "Can you find enough wealth to **free a slave**?". The man replied "No.". The nabi asked "Can you have **fast for 60 successive days**?". The man replied "No.". In the meanwhile, a basket of date fruit was brought to the nabi, he donated the fruits to the man and said him to **distribute those fruits to the poor people**. When the man said that there is no person in the area who is poorer than him, the nabi said to the man "Go to your family with these and **eat these fruits with them**."
>   (Sources: *Buhârî: Savm 30, Hibe 20, Nafakât 13, Keffârat 2-4; Müslim: Sıyâm 81; 
>   Ebû Davûd: Tahâre 123, Savm 37*).

This hadith raised different ideas among scholars:

- Some said that anyone who breaks his fast without any excuse must
  fast for 60 successive days.
- And some said that this hadith is a practical solution (or a simple
  friendly advice for that man) in that specific situation only. What
  would nabi decide if there wasn't a basket of fruits arrived at that
  moment? Maybe the nabi would had given a different prescription for
  him.

A different hadith says that it is impossible to compensate a broken fast:

> If someone breaks a fast in Ramadan, without being diseased or having any kind of excuse, he cannot compensate that fast even if he has fast for his entire life.
>   (Sources: *Buhari: Savm 29; Tirmizi: Savm 27; Ebu Davud: Savm 3*).

Therefore, there is no general direct order from nabi about what to do when someone intentionally breaks his/her fast, other than doing tawba. And, there is no common thought about it among the scholars.

There is an ayah about 60 day fasting, but it is about a totally different subject:

> وَمَا كَانَ لِمُؤْمِنٍ أَن يَقْتُلَ مُؤْمِنًا إِلاَّ خَطَئًا وَمَن قَتَلَ مُؤْمِنًا خَطَئًا فَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مُّؤْمِنَةٍ وَدِيَةٌ مُّسَلَّمَةٌ إِلَى أَهْلِهِ إِلاَّ أَن يَصَّدَّقُواْ فَإِن كَانَ مِن قَوْمٍ عَدُوٍّ لَّكُمْ وَهُوَ مْؤْمِنٌ فَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مُّؤْمِنَةٍ وَإِن كَانَ مِن قَوْمٍ بَيْنَكُمْ وَبَيْنَهُمْ مِّيثَاقٌ فَدِيَةٌ مُّسَلَّمَةٌ إِلَى أَهْلِهِ وَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مُّؤْمِنَةً فَمَن لَّمْ يَجِدْ **فَصِيَامُ شَهْرَيْنِ مُتَتَابِعَيْنِ** تَوْبَةً مِّنَ اللّهِ وَكَانَ اللّهُ عَلِيمًا حَكِيمًا
>   And never is it for a believer to kill a believer except by mistake. And whoever kills a believer by mistake - then the freeing of a believing slave and a compensation payment presented to the deceased's family [is required] unless they give [up their right as] charity. But if the deceased was from a people at war with you and he was a believer - then [only] the freeing of a believing slave; and if he was from a people with whom you have a treaty - then a compensation payment presented to his family and the freeing of a believing slave. And whoever does not find [one or cannot afford to buy one] - then [instead], **a fast for two months consecutively**, [seeking] acceptance of repentance from Allah . And Allah is ever Knowing and Wise.
>   [Nisa 92 (4/92)](http://quran.com/4/92)

Comment: I think the question is how to make up for the fast that you broke knowingly without any excuse. For a big part, it is off topic.

Comment: DVers have nothing to comment. I would like to know if I did any mistakes in my answer.

Comment: Idealogy of Sin/Tuba is not asked here. Anyways I left a +ve comment without down voting.

Answer (score 4):

According to Shi'a faith, if one breaks a fast intentionally, one must do a Qadha fast and also give "Kaffarah" for that fast.

> The Kaffarah of leaving out a fast of Ramadhan is to:
>
> free a slave, or
>
> fast for two months or
>
> feed sixty poor to their fill or give one mudd (= 3/4 kg.) of food-stuff, like, wheat or barley or bread etc. to each of them.
>
> And if it is not possible for him to fulfil any of these, he should
>   give Sadaqa according to his means and seek Divine forgiveness. And
>   the obligatory precaution is that he should give Kaffarah as and when
>   he is capable to do so.

Reference [here](http://sistani.org/index.php?p=251364&id=48&pid=2276)

Let me know if you need references from other Mujtahids.

Comment: should the fasting for 2 months be continuous?

Comment: Yes, that is consecutive 2 months. If you miss any day, you start from the beginning. This harsh punishment is so that people will not just go and break fast when they want.

Answer (score 0):

If you break fast intentionally in Ramadan without any excuse, **you have to keep 2 months of fasting continuously** to make up for one fast. Note the two conditions: 60 days fasting and continuously for one fast.

If you  broke two fasts, you have to observe 60*2 = 120 fasts. The first 60 fast will be continous and the second 60 fasts would be continuous.

[Sources 1](http://islam.about.com/od/ramadan/f/makingup.htm):

source 2: I heard this originally from Imam in the mosque. When he said this, there was a roar in the crowd because people were not expecting it and thought this was excessive (ad probably he made up himself). But I found an online link and therefor posted it as answer.